# Not finding an Existing table in hbase with data stored by a Websphere 8 Application

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I'm experiencing an issue when i attempt to start up an application on Websphere which stores its data in HBASE. I've checked HBASE and found that the database is intact and no inconsistencies were showing when I ran the `hbase hbck -fix`. Log file of the application shows:

> HConnectionMa W
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation
>   prefetchRegionCache Encountered problems when prefetch META table:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableNotFoundException: Cannot find row in
>   .META. for table: fmsfauditPreferences,
>   row=fmsfauditPreferences,,99999999999999

Any ideas aside from dropping the db and recreating it?